# C# short if statement

Tags: c#

Is there a way to do this in C# without making a new method to overload for every var type there is?

```
$box = !empty($toy) : $toy ? "";
```

The only ways I can think of to do it is either:

```
if (toy != null)
{
    box += toy; 
}
```

or this:

```
public string emptyFilter(string s) ...
public int emptyFilter(int i) ...
public bool emptyFilter(bool b) ...
public object emptyFilter(object o) 
{
    try 
    {
        if (o != null)
        {
            return o.ToString(); 
        }
        else 
        {
            return ""; 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "exception thrown": 
    }
}

box += this.emptyFilter(toy);
```

I basically wanna check to make sure that the variable/property is set/not empty/exists/has value/etc... and return it or "" without some ridiculous about of code like above.

Comment: Use Generics to create a function that can accept a type of T.

Comment: It's difficult to suggest a solution because it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Also, what does "every var type there is" mean?

Comment: in C#: String.Empty + null == String.Empty

Comment: @Jon: In C# you have to define the type of all variables/objects/etc. In one of my examples above, I made a method that could be overloaded for each type (int, string, etc..). I am trying to check if a value exists with very little code so it doesn't throw an exception. If I just do this `box += toy;` and toy is null, an exception will be thrown. My above 2 examples are just too much code as I'm doing this 50+ times in the same function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
return variable ?? default_value;
```

That what you're going for? I'm a little confused considering you're showing PHP code and tag this with C#.

There's also the [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) type you can use.

---

How bout an extender class?

```
public static class ToStringExtender
{
  public static String ToStringExt(this Object myObj)
  {
    return myObj != null ? myObj.ToString() : String.Empty;
  }
}

var myobject = foo.ToStringExt()
```

**[DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/XrcJL)**

Comment: He wants to know the C# equivalent for the PHP example.

Comment: @BoltClock: Ah, kind of starting to see it now.

Comment: I was just using the PHP short-hand version as an example as I'm familiar with it. Any way to do this in a short way in C# would be gratefully welcomed. Can I do this with that `box += var ?? def`? I don't want any exceptions thrown.

Comment: @PiZzl3: check out the demo I have in my answer, that's as short as I can see making it.

Comment: Will that work for all types (int, string, bool, etc...). VS says I can't use the ?? on strings or bools.

Comment: @piZzl3: that my my mistake, the ?? symbolizes shorthand for "ValueOrDefault" on a nullable type. But yes, that should work on all types. (Though `Int32`, `Double`, etc. by nature are not nullable, you should automatically have their value returned (as a string). (See http://www.ideone.com/wsDk6 )

Answer (score 19):

You could use the [conditional operator (`?:`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
string box = (toy != null) ? toy.ToString() : "";
```

Comment: lol, well isn't that simple.. It's amazing how similar most programming languages are. Thank you for the example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what he wants, BUT:

```
string str = String.Empty;
str += true;
str += 5;
str += new object();
str += null;
```

This is perfectly legal. For each one adition the `ToString()` will be called. For null, simply nothing will be added.

The value of str at the end: `True5System.Object`

Answer (score 0):

or,

```
var s = (toy?? "").ToString();
```

or

```
var s = (toy?? string.Empty).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think there may be a slight misunderstanding about how var is used; but that's a separate topic.
maybe this below will help:

```
box += (toy ?? "").ToString();
```